# Efficient way of computing Kullback–Leibler divergence in Python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy, statistics

I have to compute the [Kullback-Leibler Divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) (KLD) between thousands of discrete probability vectors. Currently I am using the following code but it's way too slow for my purposes. I was wondering if there is any faster way to compute KL Divergence?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sc

    #n is the number of data points
    kld = np.zeros(n, n)
        for i in range(0, n):
            for j in range(0, n):
                if(i != j):
                    kld[i, j] = sc.entropy(distributions[i, :], distributions[j, :])
```

Comment: how can i use scipy to get the generator of a probability distribution with min KL divergence in python?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Scipy's [`stats.entropy`](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html) in its default sense invites inputs as 1D arrays giving us a scalar, which is being done in the listed question. Internally this function also allows [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), which we can *abuse* in here for a vectorized solution.

From the [`docs`](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html) -

> scipy.stats.entropy(pk, qk=None, base=None)
>
> If only probabilities pk
>   are given, the entropy is calculated as S = -sum(pk * log(pk),
>   axis=0).
>
> If qk is not None, then compute the Kullback-Leibler divergence S =
>   sum(pk * log(pk / qk), axis=0).

In our case, we are doing these entropy calculations for each row against all rows, performing sum reductions to have a scalar at each iteration with those two nested loops. Thus, the output array would be of shape `(M,M)`, where `M` is the number of rows in input array.

Now, the catch here is that `stats.entropy()` would sum along `axis=0`, so we will feed it two versions of `distributions`, both of whom would have the rowth-dimension brought to `axis=0` for reduction along it and the other two axes interleaved - `(M,1)` & `(1,M)` to give us a `(M,M)` shaped output array using `broadcasting`.

Thus, a vectorized and much more efficient way to solve our case would be -

```
from scipy import stats
kld = stats.entropy(distributions.T[:,:,None], distributions.T[:,None,:])
```

Runtime tests and verify -

```
In [15]: def entropy_loopy(distrib):
    ...:     n = distrib.shape[0] #n is the number of data points
    ...:     kld = np.zeros((n, n))
    ...:     for i in range(0, n):
    ...:         for j in range(0, n):
    ...:             if(i != j):
    ...:                 kld[i, j] = stats.entropy(distrib[i, :], distrib[j, :])
    ...:     return kld
    ...: 

In [16]: distrib = np.random.randint(0,9,(100,100)) # Setup input

In [17]: out = stats.entropy(distrib.T[:,:,None], distrib.T[:,None,:])

In [18]: np.allclose(entropy_loopy(distrib),out) # Verify
Out[18]: True

In [19]: %timeit entropy_loopy(distrib)
1 loops, best of 3: 800 ms per loop

In [20]: %timeit stats.entropy(distrib.T[:,:,None], distrib.T[:,None,:])
10 loops, best of 3: 104 ms per loop
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you.

Comment: @Amir Glad to help. Even I didn't know scipy's entropy would support broadcasting and it did, and that's the best thing NumPy has!

Comment: That's exactly I thought and it made me even don't go about trying it!
Could you please give me a reference for on why you wrote the matrix variables like this "distrib.T[:,:,None]" and this "distrib.T[:,None,:]"?
What does the **None** do and why do you transpose those two matrices?

Comment: @Amir I don't really have a reference, but just the fact that it worked with unequally but broadcastable shaped arrays has to be broadcasting that NumPy uses. I could not locate any source code to say that with evidence though.

Comment: @Amir That None or [`np.newaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) is to bring in singleton dimension or a way to extend dimensions to a 3D array from the existing 2D array shape. That transpose is needed because internally that function sums across axis = 0, which is to replicate the sum of all elementwise multiplied elements that we would get in the loopy code of the question with each iteration. Hope that made sense!

Comment: Is there a way to modify this so that we only calculate `kld` between the first row and all other rows in the `distributions` matrix? In sudo code we would have something like `stats.entropy(distribution["row0"], distribution["all_other_rows"])`. Thanks

Comment: @KillianTattan I guess `stats.entropy(distributions[0,None].T, distributions[1:].T)`.

Comment: ```
   2668         qk = asarray(qk)
   2669         if qk.shape != pk.shape:
-> 2670             raise ValueError("qk and pk must have same shape.")
   2671         qk = 1.0*qk / np.sum(qk, axis=axis, keepdims=True)
   2672         vec = rel_entr(pk, qk)

ValueError: qk and pk must have same shape.